# Qt Creator + MITK (Linux)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, vtk, itk, mitk

I'm trying to use **MITK with Qt Creator**. I've successfully compiled and used VTK and ITK with ccmake.

I've compiled MITK in **superbuild mode** (it downloads CTK, VTK, ITK, etc). Then I've configured it. I've compiled with make (About two hours).

I've tried *make install*, but MITK doesn't work that way.

With GDCM, ITK, VTK, I could find header files in */usr/local/include* and shared libs in */usr/local/lib*, so I included those in my .pro file in the Qt Creator project and start working.

I've been looking inside *MITK-superbuild* folder -after compilation-, but I can't find, for example, *QmitkRenderWindow.h*, and it's the first one I need.

I'm looking into MITK doc:
http://docs.mitk.org/nightly-qt4/BuildInstructionsPage.html

I have an existing project with a .pro file, so I don't know how to continue.

Edited: ok, following this:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-project-cmake.html
and the previous link, I created a *CMakeLists.txt* and changed the build directory to *MITK-build* folder.

Now I have autocomplete adding .h headers into code. I have to navigate into subfolders.

Is MITK-build the right folder to add? I say this because *QmitkRenderWindow.h* is not there, it's in *MITK-src*, which I've downloaded before compiling MITK.

Answer (score 2):

Two alternate suggestions (I couldn't try cause I m right now stuck with MITK build with some other configuration ) based on way that I used to make project using Creator for ITK and VTK projects

1. If you want to use MITK using .pro file I can just give a clue (based on ITK/VTK settings for .pro) add path of all libs and header files path as below (which I used for VTK)

   INCLUDEPATH *= E:/DebugLibrary/VTK E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Common E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Filtering E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/GenericFiltering E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Graphics E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/GUISupport/Qt E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Hybrid E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Imaging E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/IO E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Parallel E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Rendering E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Utilities E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/VolumeRendering E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Widgets E:/DebugLibrary/VTK/Wrapping

   LIBS *= -LE:/DebugLibrary/VTKBin/bin/release -lvtkCommon -lvtksys -lQVTK -lvtkWidgets -lvtkRendering -lvtkGraphics -lvtkImaging -lvtkIO -lvtkFiltering -lvtkDICOMParser -lvtkpng -lvtktiff -lvtkzlib -lvtkjpeg -lvtkexpat -lvtkNetCDF -lvtkexoIIc -lvtkftgl -lvtkfreetype -lvtkHybrid -lvtkVolumeRendering -lQVTKWidgetPlugin -lvtkGenericFiltering
2. If you want to use Qt Creator + Cmake (within Qt) just select nmake for build and then CMake and build project (you can't use qmake here).

As I told before I didn't tried but above solutions are working with VTK for me on windows

hope this may also help
[Set include path with environment variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143354/set-include-path-with-environment-variable-value)

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator supports native CMake. MITK, VTK and ITK are managed by CMake. So to use Qt Creator with a CMake Projekt, simply open the file *CMakeLists.txt* as Project File. (*File->Open File or Project ...*). As you already mentioned, VTK/ITK/MITK are supposed to be build as a shadow build, so source and build files are split in different directories. After loading the CMakeLists.txt QtCreator asks you for a directory where to build the project.

In case of the MITK Project you have to differ between superbuild and and building MITK only. As you already have a superbuild, simply change the build directory to the subdir *MITK-build*. To open the superbuild-project, choose the direcotory above. Notice that in both cases you can use the same CMakeLists.txt

Btw, to configure your build you can use the very nice gui program *cmake-gui*, which you can find in linux (apt-based) in the package *cmake-qt-gui*.

Hope that will help you. =)

Comment: Installation instructions for the latest `cmake-gui` version can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473421/how-to-install-cmake-gui-latest-version-on-ubuntu/61473422#61473422).