# Adding each subdirectory's path to qt pro file variable

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to add path of each subdir having .h file to a qt pro file variable
I found this http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-project-files.html#built-in-functions-and-control-flow for use of a for loop but don know how to use if to do above task.

> INCLUDEPATH +=$$(MITK_INCLUDE_PATH)

When I wrote this (where path variable having only outer dir's path) its allowing me to include a header in source as:

```
> #include"ITK-src/Code/BasicFilters/itkAbsImageFilter.h"
```

and qmake is running properly but when I am building this project its asking for another .h on which above .h depend. Before this I have worked with adding 3'rd party libs in which I gave path of each header file's location to `INCLUDEPATH` [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826735/qt-creator-mitk-linux/14232927#14232927) but if there is any other way I want to know possibility.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible. If your amount of source/header files changes a lot and you don't want to manage them separately in your .pro file it would probably be easiest to write a c++ executable or batch script which generates the .pro file for you.

Comment: Aren't you trying to duplicate or get a subset of INCLUDEPATH variable?

Comment: Perhaps adding something about what you want to accomplish with the list of directories would help us come up with an answer.

Comment: Please see question I added more content.