# How to install cmake-gui latest version on Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

When installing from package-manager, `cmake-gui` or `cmake-qt-gui` are shipped with an older version of `cmake`.

Even after I build and install `cmake`'s latest version from source, `cmake-gui` continues to use the older version.

How to force `cmake-gui` to use `cmake` latest version builded from source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cmake-gui` package from repository has a built-in `cmake`, those two have the same version.

Steps to install `cmake-gui` latest version.

1. Install `checkinstall` to easily remove `cmake` in the future: `sudo apt-get install checkinstall`;
2. Download latest `cmake` from official [site](https://cmake.org/download/);
3. Extract the compressed file to some folder;
4. Open a terminal inside that folder;
5. Execute: `./bootstrap --qt-gui`;
6. Execute: `checkinstall -D make install`; You will be prompted with some questions, answer them;
7. Finished installation! Type `cmake` at Ubuntu's search bar and you will see a `CMake` icon;
8. Verify the version clicking at ***help >> about***;

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above.

1. Check if you have an old version of `cmake` with `cmake --version`. If so, remove it with `sudo apt-get purge cmake`
2. Download latest cmake from official [site](https://cmake.org/download/)
3. Extract the downloaded `cmake-x.xx.x` file to your Desktop and then open a terminal inside that file.
4. Execute: `./bootstrap --qt-gui`
5. After finished, run `gmake` as prompted.
6. Move `cmake-x.xx.x` file to `/opt/` directory by going up to your `Desktop` with the terminal and then running `sudo mv cmake-x.xx.x /opt/`
7. Declare cmake binary as global by writing `export PATH=/opt/cmake-x.xx.x/bin:$PATH` in your `~.bashrc` file.
8. Source with `source .bashrc`

You will then be able to open `cmake` or `cmake-gui` with your terminal from any path in your computer.